# Where are the 17.04 checksum files located?

Tags: 17.04

I clicked on the "How to verify your Ubuntu download" link. It tells me to verify the download using the checksum files, but I have not been able to find them! At the very least, that page should contain a link. There should also be a link somewhere on the download pages. 
Most other OS download sites make it very obvious.

Comment: You find the checksums for all current Ubuntu versions and flavours via this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Answer (score 1):

For 17.04, they are here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/

As sudodus mentioned, the checksums for all current Ubuntu varieties are linked here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

For what it's worth, on the 17.04 download page, you can click [**Learn how to verify**](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu), then **Download sums**, then **Download sums and signature for Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**, then edit the url from 16.04 to 17.04, to get to http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/. I agree it's unintuitive.